# Omitir tipagem estendida TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ao utilizar a biblioteca Mongoose, a tipagem de um *model* pode ser feita com uma interface que estende o tipo `mongoose.Document`. Essa abordagem está funcionando de acordo com o exemplo abaixo:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IModel extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string;
}

const ModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: { type: String },
});

export default mongoose.model<IModel>('model', ModelSchema);
```

Na criação de uma função que é capaz de criar um documento com base nesse *model*, deve-se enviar um objeto que tem a tipagem exatamente igual a interface definida dentro do *model*, mas sem as propriedades estendidas de `mongoose.Document`. A pergunta é: Existe alguma forma de fazer a exclusão ou omissão das propriedades estendidas de `mongoose.Document`?

Segue abaixo um exemplo da função feita para criar um documento:

```js
import Model from 'models/Model';

export default async function createModelDocument(documentData: TIPO_SEM_AS_PROPRIEDADES_ESTENDIDAS): Promise<void> {
  await Model.create(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é simplesmente criar tipos separados. Um para os **dados** a serem armazenados no *model* (como `ModelData`) e o outro que, de fato, representa o modelo, formado a partir da **interseção** de `ModelData` e `mongoose.Document`.

Algo assim:

```
interface ModelData {
  name: string;
}

type Model = ModelData & mongoose.Document;
```

<sup>Saiba mais sobre os *intersection types* na [documentação](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) do TypeScript.</sup>

Em seguida você poderia usar da seguinte forma.

- Para criar o modelo:

  ```
  export default mongoose.model<Model>('model', ModelSchema);
  ```
- Para criar uma função que depende apenas dos dados do modelo:

  ```
  import Model, { ModelData } from 'models/Model';

  export default async function createModelDocument(documentData: ModelData): Promise<void> {
    await Model.create(item);
  }
  ```